# Python TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not list

Tags: python, image, sorting, time, directory

i am new on python, i wrote simple script to send all image sorted by time in folder to API. this code working on just one file(jpg), and can't send the rest of image in folder. I want to if i run this code, it's just waiting until some image added to current folder, when image is inside folder then it will send to API by time based on images that first existed. I am very confused, any helps will be appriciated! thx

```
import glob
import argparse
import requests
import json
import time
import os

def main():
    result = []

    file = glob.glob("/path/to/dir/*.jpg")

    regions = ['id']

    time_to_wait = 10000
    time_counter = 0

    while not os.path.exists(file):
        time.sleep(1)
        time_counter += 1
        if time_counter > time_to_wait: break
        print("waiting for file...")

        if os.path.isfile(file):
            with open(file, 'rb') as fp:
                response = requests.post(
                    'https://GET_API/',
                    data=dict(regions=regions),
                    files=dict(upload=fp),
                    headers={'Authorization': 'Token ' + 'XXX'})
                result.append(response.json())
                resp_dict = json.loads(json.dumps(result, indent=2))
                if resp_dict[0]['results']:
                    num=resp_dict[0]['results'][0]['plate']
                    print(f"DETECTED NUMBER:  {num}")
                os.remove(file)

    else:
        print("file doesn't exists!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't update your `file` on each iteration. Maybe that's why no more new files are detected. `file` also need to be treated as a list, so I guess you should iterate through `file`. Your while loop should look like this:

```
while True:
    files = glob.glob(os.path.join('path', 'to', 'dir', '*.jpg'))
    for file in files:
        if os.path.isfile(file):
            with open(file, 'rb') as fp:
                # Upload and delete
    # sleep
```

Comment: thankyou very much, i'm looking for this all day. thankyou!